# Baselinker api GET method

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have a problem with code. I try to get list of products and stocks from Baselinker. I receive 200 response but unfortunately also have response:

```
{'status': 'ERROR', 'error_code': 'ERROR_UNKNOWN_METHOD', 
 'error_message': 'An empty or unknown method has been used'}
```

I think I made mistake with methods definition but I try everything I can and problem still exist.

```
import requests
import json
import webbrowser
from pprint import pprint

params = {
    "inventory_id": "1762"
}

parameters = json.dumps(params)

headers = {
    "X-BLToken" : token,
    'method': "getInventoryProductsStock",
    'parameters': parameters
}

response = requests.get('https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php', headers=headers)

print(response)
show = response.json()
print(show)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters should not be placed in a header. You should send a POST request (not a GET) with data, containing 'method' key and optionally 'parameters'.

Try this:

```
import json
import requests

data = {
    "method": "getInventoryProductsStock"
    "parameters": json.dumps({"inventory_id": 1762})   
}

headers = {
    "X-BLToken" : token,
}

response = requests.post('https://api.baselinker.com/connector.php', headers=headers, data=data)

print(response)
show = response.json()
print(show)
```